# node.js - stream http response from multiple calls

Tags: node.js, api, http, express, stream

In my express app, I want to make multiple calls to an API and stream each response back to the client as and when I receive it, instead of waiting for all of them.

For example, if I make requests to yelp for restaurants in San Francisco, Berkeley and Palo Alto in parallel, I shouldn't have to wait for all the responses to come back and be able stream them as they're available. How would I do this?

Comment: If you are going to restructure the API data server side for your response, then you must wait for the data from both external APIs.

Comment: If you want JSON data, you'll need to make multiple calls to the server and fetch them in batches (as you can't partially send JSON back), or use sockets/long polling to "push" the data as it's completed.

Comment: What does your response object look like?  JSON?  What is receiving it?  There are streaming specifications for JSON-like data available.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another question. Since it's kind of similar to the earlier one, I just updated that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since browsers wait till the *entire response* is received before passing the result to javascript, this isn't directly possible. You could, on the other hand, do it with websockets.

Possible architecture:

1. *Server*: Establish websocket connection with client
2. *Server*: Fire off 4 requests to APIs in parallel
3. *Server*: As data arrives on each connection, pass each packet to the websocket with something like `{api: "yelp", data: ... }`
4. *Client*: Keep appending incoming data to strings representing each api's response.
5. *Server*: When a connection is done, send a done message `{ api: "yepl", done: true }`
6. *Client*: Upon receiving a done message, you have a full response from that API.

**I highly doubt this is a good idea**. It's far more complex and you'd be better off using 4 parallel requests from the client, or if possible, querying the apis directly from the browser.